# SWT Load Font in a RCP App

Tags: java, fonts, swt, eclipse-rcp

Here's what I want to do:

```
Display.getCurrent().loadFont("fonts/helveticaNeueBold_iOS7.ttf")
```

- **Works** in a tester (*i.e. class with entry point*).
- **Doesn't** work in an RCP app.

How do the loading mechanisms differ? Should I *get* the `ttf` file, then extract the path to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981868/swt-load-font-in-a-rcp-app/19983685#19983685) could also be helpful to some.

For me, the following snippet did the trick:

```
final String path = "fonts/helveticaNeueBold_iOS7.ttf";
final URL pathUrl = BundleUtility.find(PLUGIN_ID, path);
final boolean isFontLoaded = Display.getCurrent().loadFont(pathUrl.toExternalForm());
```

Although beware that `BundleUtility` has restricted access.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse bundles have different paths (something like "bundleentry://bundle_number/path_to_your_file"). You might want to use `FileLocator` to load files properly. For example:

```
Bundle bundle = Activator.getDefault().getBundle();
Path path = new Path("fonts/helveticaNeueBold_iOS7.ttf");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
URL fileUrl = null;
try {
fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
}
catch (IOException e) {
// Will happen if the file cannot be read for some reason
e.printStackTrace();
}
File file = new File(fileUrl.getPath());
boolean loadFont = Display.getCurrent().loadFont(file.toString());
```

Also, please check other methods, available within `FileLocator`.

Comment: File loads, but font doesn't. The `loadFont` API returns `FALSE`.

Comment: What path were you trying to use in loadFont method?

Comment: Please, to do it like this: Display.getCurrent().loadFont(file.toString());