# How to load font not installed on system

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

From an eclipse plugin I want to modify the default editor text font, I managed tp do that by:
`WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().put(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT, "dummy font values");`

The problem is that the font which I want to set(`Source Code Pro`) is not installed in the system and it's not supposed to be installed.

I downloaded the font from [here](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/2.030R-ro%2F1.050R-it), but I didn't find a way to load the font from the downloaded files and set it as value for the `JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT` prefs entry.

The `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device` has a method `loadFont(String path)` which looks promising, but the `Display.getCurrent()` returns `null` in my plugin.

How can I load a font from a file?
How do I set the font in my plugin after I loaded it?

Comment: `Display.getCurrent` will only work in the UI thread - it returns null in any other thread,

Comment: @greg-449 I found out later when debugging, I forgot to put the code in a `runSync( new Runnable() {});`. I will add the solution, maybe it will be useful for somebody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following snippet. It will work in most of the cases. I got this snippet by referring to the SO question link ---> [Load a font in RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981868/swt-load-font-in-a-rcp-app/19983685#19983685)

```
final String path = "fonts/helveticaNeueBold_iOS7.ttf";
final URL pathUrl = BundleUtility.find(PLUGIN_ID, path);
final String filePathAsString = FileLocator.toFileURL(pathUrl).getPath().toString();
final boolean isFontLoaded = Display.getCurrent().loadFont(filePathAsString);
```

Comment: It's not working, unfortunately. The `BundleUtility.find()` returns a value with the format `bundleentry://24.fwk24119573/fonts/SourceCodePro-BoldIt.ttf`. When the `loadForm`  is called, it calls `OS.AddFontResourceEx` which returns false

Comment: I added some corrections which fixed the problem for me